# How to run unit tests by category in Rider?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, rider

I want to run NUnit Tests from Rider's Unit Tests Explorer filtered by Category. Rider 2017.1. Is it possible? When it will be possible, if planned to implement?

Comment: This feature is not supported in Rider 2017.1, here is the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2316

Comment: This is good answer, but why in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported in Rider 2017.1, here is the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2316

**Update:** The category support was introduced in Rider 2019.1. You can find more information in this [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2019/04/08/unit-testing-improvements-rider-2019-1/).

Answer (score 3):

Rider 2019.1.1 supports it.

For class:

[image]

```cs
[TestFixture, Category("Regression_Test")]
class className
{
    [Test]
    public void functionOne()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

For function:

[image]

```cs
class className
{
    [Test, Category("Regression_Test")]
    public void FunctionOne()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```